# Proper with "Executing Custom PHP Code" Action

Tags: 7, rules, actions

I am trying to add an action that "Executes Custom PHP Code". I click Add a new action to the rule I have created and I choose "Execute Custom PHP Code" from the drop down the loading spinner appears for a couple of seconds and then disappear. The only thing I can do is click Continue which does nothing.

Then when i navigate to another page I receive the follow error

> Value field is required.
>
> The integrity check failed with the following error message: "Missing configuration for parameter code."

Has anybody got any idea why this is coming up.

It sounds like a box is supposed to appear but it doesn't.

As far as I can see I have all the right modules installed. (PHP filter, Rules, Rules Scheduler, Rules UI, Trigger).

Oh I am using Drupal 7.7 (I am planning on upgrading to 7.8 later today)

Thanks

Conor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I solved it, It turned out to be very simple. *Facepalm*

I had misconfigured nodejs which was causing a javascript error. Which meant the textbox which should've appeared didn't.

I reconfigured nodejs and it worked fine :)